# Использование частицы «не»

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, частица, диалог

Можно ли использовать частицу "не" в следующем случае?
"Приказ подписывают до сентября. НЕ, их подписывают еще в августе."

Answer (score 2):

Да, такое употребление частицы "не" в предложениях разговорного стиля возможно.
В словаре Ожегова:
[**НЕ**](http://endic.ru/ozhegov/Ne-17869.html), частица
7. То же, что нет (в I знач.) (прост.). *— Хочешь чаю. — Не.*

> ― Ты чего там молчишь?
> ― Хочу и молчу.
> **― Не, так не пойдет.** Раз уж звонишь по телефону, изволь говорить что-нибудь.
> [Дмитрий Коваленин. Кофейные зерна // «Домовой», 2002.12.04]

Ваши предложения — это, скорее всего, диалог, и оформлен он неверно.

Если реплики диалога даются каждая с абзаца, то перед ними ставится тире:
*— Приказ подписывают до сентября.

— Не, их подписывают еще в августе.*

Если реплики следуют в подбор, без указания, кому они принадлежат, то каждая из них заключается в кавычки и отделяется от соседней тире:
*«Приказ подписывают до сентября». — «Не, их подписывают еще в августе».*

[§ 52. Знаки препинания при диалоге](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154)